# How to monitor multiple JNDI datasources with FlexyPool?

Tags: flexy-pool

I am starting to use FlexyPool to monitor an JNDI datasource managed by Tomcat.

I found how to monitor one datasource in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611056/how-i-can-use-flexypool-with-hikaricpfactory) and in FlexyPool [doc](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool/wiki/Java-EE-Configuration). I can not, however, figure how to configure the monitoring of multiple sources through the flexy-pool.properties file. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the declarative configuration only supports a single DataSource. You can open an issue on GitHub for this. I would not mind if you send a Pull request for it.